# как исправить ошибку: socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed?

Tags: python

**Ошибка:**

> ... for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>
> socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

**Python Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request
from lxml.html import parse

WEBSITE = 'http://allrecipes.com'

URL_PAGE = 'http://allrecipes.com/recipes/110/appetizers-and-snacks/deviled-eggs/?page='

START_PAGE = 1
END_PAGE = 5

def correct_str(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()

for i in range(START_PAGE, END_PAGE+1):
    URL = URL_PAGE + str(i)
    HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

    page = parse(HTML).getroot()

        # пропускаем видео
    for elem in page.xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/article[not(contains(@class, "video-card"))]/a[1]'):
        href = WEBSITE + elem.get('href')
        title = correct_str(elem.find('h3').text)

        recipe_page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(href)).getroot()
        photo_url = recipe_page.xpath('//img[@class="rec-photo"]')[0].get('src')

        print('\nName:  |', title)
        print('Photo: |', photo_url)
```

**Console - Results:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Name:  | Crab-Stuffed Deviled Eggs
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1240, in do_open
Photo: | http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/720x405/1091564.jpg
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 826, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/In/Dropbox/parser/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    recipe_page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(href)).getroot()
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 465, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 483, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1268, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\In\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1242, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

getaddrinfo failed в самом простом случае возникает, если для предоставленного URL не получается найти адрес. Например, "http://google", "localhos", "http://slkdfj.com"

Для полной картины можно почитать: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html в зависимости от используемой ОС

К примеру, вот что говорит MSDN про эту ошибку: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND

```
No such host is known. The name is not an official host name or alias, 
or it cannot be found in the database(s) being queried. This error may also
be returned for protocol and service queries, and means that the specified
name could not be found in the relevant database.
```

В более сложных случаях все зависит от настроек сети, firewall.

Comment: спасибо за ссылки, но я английской лишь малось понимаю.   
я так понял с того что вы написали, нужно открыть порт , вопрос какой  ?
ещё нужно что-то прописать в код `python`'a ?

Comment: Не нужно портов открывать, если не закрывали их до этого. Нужны порты 80 (HTTP) или 443 (HTTPS). Если проблема не в настройках сети (тут уж удаленно не угадаешь), то проблема в неверном адресе страницы в переменной href.

Comment: скрипт вчера работал, сегодня запустил и выдал ошибку.
уж точно ошибка не в адресе страницы переменой `href`

Comment: вот вопрос тогда в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Пока было предложено 2 причины - неверный адрес и проблемы с сетью или сетевым экраном. От первой причины можно отказаться только если напечатать адрес в консоль и убедиться, что он гарантированно верный. Можно это автоматизировать - есть библиотека https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validators. Со второй причиной все намного сложнее, потому что конфигурация вашей ОС неизвестна, но если с этой машины и с этим пользователем можно выйти в интернет, то у меня нет решений. Проблемы с сетью можно проверить, запустив строку urllib.request.urlopen("h_ttp://google.com")

Comment: Ответ в консоле `<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x03642C30>` на команду `>>> urllib.request.urlopen("http://allrecipes.com")`

Comment: Кстати, минутка законопослушности. Стоит почитать http://www.meredith.com/datapolicy.html и http://dish.allrecipes.com/customer-service/terms-of-service/. Там написано, что владелец совсем не хочет, чтобы по его ресурсу шарились боты и что-либо скачивали без письменного разрешения.

Comment: хм.. если бы меня забанили, я бы не мог попасть на сайт

Comment: Нет, проблема не в этом. Повторюсь в четвертый раз - проблема в том, что DNS не может определить IP адрес ресурса - еще никаких обращений к сайту не было. Так бывает, если ваш сетевой экран блокирует запросы или такого ресурса не существует.

Comment: все разобрался в чем дело )

Comment: Так в чем конкретно? Если мой ответ неверен, вы можете ответить на свой собственный вопрос.

Comment: в переменою `href` попадала неверна ссылка: `http://allrecipes.comhttp://dish.allrecipes.com/how-to-boil-an-egg/`